# Returning rows with different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

Having a big challenges with this most likely quite easy problem, hopefully somebody can help me, thank you very much in advance!

I have a MySql table with fields (A, B, C, D, E, F and G) and example data like in below;

A | B | C | D | E | F | G

1 | 0 | 0 | K | M | V | K

0 | 1 | 0 | H | L | P | Z

0 | 0 | 1 | G | W | Y | X

I want make a SQL -query which will work like this:

if A is 1 then return field A and D

OR

if B is 1 then return field B and F

OR

if C is 1 then return field C and E

so the output from the query would be something like this;

A | B | C | D | E | F

1 |   |   | K |   |

| 1 |  |  |  | P |

|  | 1 |  | W |

Is this possible?

Your help is much appreciated, thank you.

Kind Regards,

JH

Comment: What if more than one of `(A,B,C)` are 1; or none are?

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
SELECT
 CASE WHEN A = 1 THEN A ELSE NULL END AS A,
 CASE WHEN B = 1 THEN B ELSE NULL END AS B,
 CASE WHEN C = 1 THEN C ELSE NULL END AS C,
 CASE WHEN A = 1 THEN D ELSE NULL END AS D,
 CASE WHEN C = 1 THEN E ELSE NULL END AS E,
 CASE WHEN B = 1 THEN F ELSE NULL END AS F

FROM YourTable
```

Comment: From the example, it looks like OP wants to return all the columns, but with nulls in the non-applicable columns.